# New horrible appearance?

Tags: support, design

Does anybody know if the present appearance of main TeX site, in black and blue, and all elements in strange places is a temporary bug or a new, disgusting idea?

I have checked some other sites and they are not spoiled.

[image]

Comment: 'horrible' depends on personal views. It's the mobile version, which is quite convenient for, well, mobile phones, but not for real questioning or answering.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking at the mobile version of the site. (Which means you must have clicked "mobile" in the footer to get there). To escape, scroll down and click "full site" in the footer.